# Can non-biological matter cause your sink, dishes, or food to become non-kosher?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher

For instance, if something non-edible such as a chemical or eraser shavings are drained down the sink, would that cause any kashrut problems?

Comment: Are they edible material? What about water?

Comment: There is discussion about minerals being kosher as far as gold and tefillin goes, to consider gold min humutar bificha. However, pouring something nonkosher down a drain is almost never an issue. Unless your Jewish plumber had removed the trap and placed his mouth around the open pipe. That would be problematic. But under normal circumstances, just wash the chemical down with cold water. Soap too, to help you feel better.

Comment: @Yishai I'm thinking mostly non-edible. With water, the issue is the same. Does it become non-kosher if some other non-biological matter is mixed in?

Comment: @user6591 "Unless your Jewish plumber had removed the trap and placed his mouth around the open pipe. That would be problematic." Yes, you'd potentially be liable for murder...

Comment: Plastic can become problematic acc to some opinions

Answer (score 2):

Inedible nonbiological matter has Kashrus neutral status. It is not, nor can it become, non kosher. Completely inedible matter also has Kashrus neutral status. This would include completely inedible matter of biological origin as well as completely inedible mixtures containing biological matter (For example,detergent or drain cleaners are Kashrus neutral due to their complete inedibility, regardless of biological ingredients contained in them.)[source](http://cor.ca/view/180/does_it_really_need_to_be_kosher_certified.html) This is because the Torah only permits or forbids the eating of food, and is never concerned with the consumption of non-food.

In rare cases, you might have an issue with blios, that is, absorption of taste from edible matter. For example, a metal pot (Kashrus neutral) used to cook non kosher food can absorb taste from the non kosher food.

Comment: What if the metal shavings are a tikrovet avoda zara?

Comment: Can you cite a specific place in that extensive work which makes the claims you attribute to it?

Comment: @DoubleAA They are asur b'hanaah, but that's not a kashrus issue per se.

Comment: So yayin nesach is kosher but just asur behana?

Comment: What if the non-edible substance were poisonous? It is forbidden to eat something poisonous. Your sink, dishes, etc. could become not useable for food, and any food that became poisonous would not be fit to eat. So poison would render kosher food not edible.

Comment: @DoubleAA Yayin Nesech is edible. Nonedible items (like tikrovet avoda zara) are asur b'hanaah. The taste of a non edible item is not considered hanaah.

Comment: @YehudaW Could be.

Comment: What about salt that is tikrovet avoda zara?

Comment: @DoubleAA Salt is edible.

Comment: Its not biological

Comment: DoubleAA good one, Also water, (that was served for an avoda zorah) if thirsty (if not thirsty not hanoo)

Comment: @hazoriz , DoubleAA I edited the post to clarify your points.

Answer (score -3):

the laws of kosher are discussed in the torah in parsha shmini [(Lev.11)](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9912/jewish/Chapter-11.htm).

there it discusses the kosher status of fish, animals and birds.

no mention of plants or inanimate materials. so we can assume none of those are forbidden regarding kosher

Comment: What happened to Orlah/Revai/Kilayim/Tevel/Chadash/Bikkurim/Terumot/Maaserot/Sefichim/Yeinam?

Comment: you left something out? how about venishmartem?

Comment: Oh I forgot Challah.

Comment: @DoubleAA what happened to avodah zara (ashera), hekdesh, nidrei isur, cheremim?

Comment: What about them?

Comment: the reason plants are permitted as food is an explicit verse in genesis 1:29.